# Regex is not marking the correct tag

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
case when regexp_like(
    lower(ht_s), 
    '.*wind.?(6\.1|7|8|10|11|.*(ce|vi|xp).*)|.*work.*|.*mc.*'
  ) then 'Cli'
  when regexp_like(
    lower(ht_s), 
    '.*(arise
     |fevax|vm[ww]are|wind).*'
  ) then 'Ser'
    ELSE 'Others' END AS "Dev Ty"
```

This regex is giving me the correct result but
wind.ce is suppose to be "cli" which is giving me correct result
but "wind center" is suppose to be marked as "Ser" It is getting marked as "cli"
I dont know where I am doing something wrong ,The main thing which getting me this is marked as bold

data example with expected output

```
                dev ty(expected ouput)  coming Output
Wind datacenter Ser                     Cli
wind ce 5.x     Cli                     Cli
```

Comment: any help regarding this

Comment: It's being marked as "cli" because your regex is allowing that. Without any sample data, logic, and expected output, it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve with the code you have.

Comment: @PhilCoulson hi phil just provided the data with expected output and coming output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we break out those two regexp into there own columns, so we can separate the CASE from the REGEXP:

```
select 
    column1 as ht_s,
    regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind.?(6\.1|7|8|10|11|.*(ce|vi|xp).*)|.*work.*|.*mc.*' ) as r1,
    regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*(arise|fevax|vm[ww]are|wind).*' ) as r2,
    case 
        when r1 then 'Cli'
        when r2 then 'Ser'
        else 'Others' 
    end as "Dev Ty",
from values
    ('Wind datacenter'),
    ('wind ce 5.x');
```

| HT_S | R1 | R2 | Dev Ty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wind datacenter | TRUE | TRUE | Cli |
| wind ce 5.x | TRUE | TRUE | Cli |

So just as Phil notes, this is just a REGEXP problem, and you need to improve you first regexp, thus we can ignore the CASE part.

For the data you have presented, the first regex `'.*wind.?(6\.1|7|8|10|11|.*(ce|vi|xp).*)|.*work.*|.*mc.*'` can be trimmed down to the parts that are in affect: `'.*wind.*ce.*'`

```
select 
    column1 as ht_s
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind.?(6\.1|7|8|10|11|.*(ce|vi|xp).*)|.*work.*|.*mc.*' ) as r1
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind.*ce.*' ) as r2
from values
    ('Wind datacenter'),
    ('Wind center'),
    ('wind ce 5.x');
```

which is matches anything with a `ce` in it after `wind`

| HT_S | R1 | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wind datacenter | TRUE | TRUE |
| Wind center | TRUE | TRUE |
| wind ce 5.x | TRUE | TRUE |

thus changing the "white space matches that you appear to be any the any token `.` and using the whitespace `/s` which needs to be escaped to `//s`

'.*wind\s?ce\s.*' only matches `wind ce`  and not the others.

so something like:

```
select 
    column1 as ht_s
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind.?(6\.1|7|8|10|11|.*(ce|vi|xp).*)|.*work.*|.*mc.*' ) as r1
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind\\s?(6\.1|7|8|10|11|\\s*(ce|vi|xp))\\s+.*' ) as r1_fix
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind.*ce.*' ) as r2
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind.*(ce ).*' ) as r3
    ,regexp_like( lower(ht_s), '.*wind\\s?ce\\s.*' ) as r4
from values
    ('Wind 6.1'),
    ('Wind 7'),
    ('Wind xp'),
    ('Wind datacenter'),
    ('Wind center'),
    ('wind ce 5.x');
```

| HT_S | R1 | R1_FIX | R2 | R3 | R4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wind 6.1 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Wind 7 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Wind xp | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Wind datacenter | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Wind center | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| wind ce 5.x | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |